# Force types in array with Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I continue to get a typescript error when attempting to assign them strict types. How do I set each item in returned array as it's own type. I want to define each item in the array as a definite type so I can use them in my doc without having to write `as string` every time I use them.

> Type '(string | string[])[]' is not assignable to type '[any, string,
> any, string[]]'.   Target requires 4 element(s) but source may have
> fewer.ts(2322)

```
    const [, currentRoute, , requiredRoutes]: [any, string, any, string[]] = useDocumentCaptureRoute(viewModel);
```

Comment: please show `useDocumentCaptureRoute`

Comment: I tried this: `const [, currentRoute, , requiredRoutes]: [any, string, any, string[]] = [1,'string', 2 ,['starray','s1array']]` and `requiredRoutes` is array of string

Comment: share reproducable example